# how to make ajax receive multiple data from php, and one of the data is in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I know JSON could help me to process multiple data from php by storing all data in an array. But what about one of the data is in a loop? See the code below:

```
$data1='<p>hehe</p>';
$data2='<h1>wawa</h1>'; 
$backarr=array($data1,$data2);

echo json_encode($backarr);
```

Now I have something that want to be data3

```
$sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username != '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $names = $row['username'];
    echo '<p>'.$names.'</p>';
}
```

Is it possible to do that? I want the ajax to receive all of the three data, how to process the data3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$backarray = array();
$backarray['data1'] = '<p>hehe</p>';
$backarray['data2'] = '<h1>wawa</h1>';


$sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username != '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $names[] = $row['username'];
}

//Push $names array into $backarray
$backarray['names'] = $names;

var_dump(json_encode($backarray));
```

which will output something like under with all names in an array.

```
'{"data1":"<p>hehe<\/p>","data2":"<h1>wawa<\/h1>","names":["Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5","Name6"]}'
```

Comment: I have tried all of the answers, they seem work, but I do not know how to pass them in ajax? Thank you.

Comment: @user2049259 Assuming `responseObject` is your response object received from ajax call, `responseObject.data1` will give you `data1`, `responseObject`.data2 will give you `data2` `responseObject.names` will give you an array of names which you can iterate by using a loop like `responseObject.names[1]`,`responseObject.names[2]`...

Comment: @user2049259 Are you using jQuery?

Comment: No, I am not using JQuery, just raw ajax, your answer works perfectly for me, thank you very much! @LoneWOLFs

Answer (score 2):

It's not that hard really:

```
$names = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{
   array_push($names, "<p>" . $row['username'] . "</p>");
}

echo json_encode($names);
```

Comment: Thank you, but what about other two data? data1 and data2 are also stored in $names?

Answer (score 0):

You could combine all in one array and then start to encode.

```
$dataSet = array();
$data1='<p>hehe</p>';
$data2='<h1>wawa</h1>'; 
$dataSet[] = $backarr = array($data1,$data2);


$sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username != '$username'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { 
    $names[] = $row['username'];
} 
$dataSet[] = $names;

echo json_encode($dataSet);
```

**EDIT::**

And here the jQuery stuff:

```
jQuery.post('url/script.php',{fieldName : fieldValue},function(res){
   console.log(res);
   var res = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
   console.log(res);
});
```

Pure AJAX:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function loadJSON()
{
   var data_file = "http://www.example.com/data.json";
   var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   try{
      // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
      http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }catch (e){
      // Internet Explorer Browsers
      try{
         http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e) {
         try{
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
   http_request.onreadystatechange  = function(){
      if (http_request.readyState == 4  )
      {
        // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);

        // jsonObj variable now contains the data structure and can
        // be accessed as jsonObj.name and jsonObj.country.
        document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML =  jsonObj.name;
        document.getElementById("Country").innerHTML = jsonObj.country;
      }
   }
   http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
   http_request.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to receive the data in ajax?
$('data1').innerHTML=myownrequest2result[0];
$('data2').innerHTML=myownrequest2result[1];
$('data3').innerHTML=myownrequest2result[2];
   
I hope the [2] should be the data3..